Config a MongoDB Kafka Sink for a Timeseries collection
I tried to sink data from a Kafka topic into a MongoDB Timeseries collection but got errors that indicate something about the Collection's metaField i.e: "com.mongodb.MongoBulkWriteException: Bulk write operation error on server mongodb2-virtual-machine:28017. Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=72, message='Cannot perform a non-multi update on a time-series collection', details={}}]"
I've searched this error in StackOverflow and saw this post which suggests to add a {multi: true} config to the query but like I said I'm not querying the DB but I'm trying to create a Sink Connector properties file. Does anybody know how to set up such a config in .properties file or how to address this issue in another way?
I am using a MongoDB replica-set version 6 with Apache Kafka version 3.3.2
